# Firestore Security Rule not allowing two uids to access a doc

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

TLDR; I want restrict reading a firestore doc to the two users that are mentioned in that doc. Firestore security rules are allowing one to access but failing for other.

---

In my ecommerce app, when customer A places an order in Shop B, an order document is added in `orders` collection. I want to setup security rules so that this order can only be read by the customer A or the shop B.

This is what the rules look like :

```
match /orders/{orderId} {
  allow read:   if request.auth.uid == resource.data.cust.uid ||
                   request.auth.uid == resource.data.shop.ownerUid;
  allow write:  if < Some Condition >;
}
```

Now while fetching orders for a customer I am querying like this, and it works OK. Security Rules pass it through.

```
let query = dbFirestore.collection('orders')
    .where("cust.uid", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .orderBy('statusHistory.New', 'desc')
    .startAfter(lastVisible)
    .limit(5);

query.get();
```

However, when i query for the shop (like below), I get permission denied error (by Security rules)

```
let query = dbFirestore.collection('orders')
    .where("shop.ownerUid", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .orderBy('statusHistory.New', 'desc')
    .startAfter(lastVisible)
    .limit(5);

query.get();
```

**Both queries are similar, yet one passes and the other fails !!!**

Another fact that i want to mention is that a customer can own a shop too, so below is one possible case :
`request.auth.uid = shop.ownerUid = cust.uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`

I am having a feeling that it may have something to do with the Rules error, but I am not on any conclusion.

---

I also tried with adding shopId in query and rules, but it still fails.

```
let query = dbFirestore.collection('orders')
    .where("shop.ownerUid", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .where("shop.shopId", "==", shopId_of_this_shop)      // <---- This
    .orderBy('statusHistory.New', 'desc')
    .startAfter(lastVisible)
    .limit(5);
```

Rules :

```
match /orders/{orderId} {
  allow read:   if request.auth.uid == resource.data.cust.uid ||
                   (request.auth.uid == resource.data.shop.ownerUid &&
                    request.resource.data.shop.shopId == resource.data.shop.shopId);
}
```

For reference, below is the data from `order` document :

[image]

[image]

I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to index not existing.

I hadn't generated index for "shop.ownerUid", and since the query was failing with the "Permission Error" and not the "Index is Required". I kept focussing on Security Rules.

Query on "cust.uid" was passing because it had the index.

Once i realised and generated the index on "shop.ownerUid" and the status field of query, it worked.